# How I could an axiom validate in Z3Py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am new to Z3, but I understand that an axiom is a premise that is assumed, regardless of whether or not it is obvious, and that it is used to demonstrate other propositions.

I am trying to define an axiom combining methods Length and Contains of Z3Py , an example of my idea is this:

```
lista = Const('lista', SeqSort(IntSort()))

a, b = Ints('a b')
solve(ForAll(lista, Length(lista)> 3))
```

It fragment of code would be considered like an axiom? It back me "no solution" and I don't understand why. Should it to back a list of two elements, true?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very confusing, not clear at all what you are asking. An axiom usually is a quantified statement, i.e., something that has `Forall` and/or `Exists` in it. Here's an example, copied from https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm:

```py
f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort())
x, y = Ints('x y')
print ForAll([x, y], f(x, y) == 0)
print Exists(x, f(x, x) >= 0)

a, b = Ints('a b')
solve(ForAll(x, f(x, x) == 0), f(a, b) == 1)
```

As you see, axioms are usually used to express properties of uninterpreted-functions: `f` in the above example.

Your description is very hard to decipher, but sounds like you might have the XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/ See if you can reformulate question with what exactly you're trying to achieve, instead of making assumptions! (Sorry for the pun!) Best of luck!

### Regarding your coding:

Let's focus on what you wrote:

```py
solve(ForAll(lista, Length(lista)> 3))
```

What you're saying here is that *for all* lists (which you named `lista`), their length is greater than 3. In more mathematical notation, you stated:

```
∀x. length (x) > 3
```

This is clearly not true, as you can take empty-list as a counter-example.

In general axioms would create a new uninterpreted sort, and/or uninterpreted functions and state properties of them. You've indicated tht you're a new user, chances are you will not need axioms for anything practical at this level. Stack overflow really works the best when you ask very specific questions about specific topics, so feel free to ask a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my first comment, I hope to be more clearly now.

Comment: Not so much, unfortunately. I tried to explain a bit more on what your encoding really means, but specific questions would work better instead of such vague statements.